# session error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

when I want to set session data in codeigniter 3 it says error like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir(): Invalid path

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 117

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-test\application\controllers\login.php
Line: 7
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-test\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Here is the code that where want to set session data.

```
$sess_array = array(
         'id' => 1,
         'username' => 'bikramkc.kc@gmail.com'
       );
$this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
```

Comment: you need to check  this load in your controller `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: update your full code

Comment: what is your line 117??

Comment: I'm guessing that line 117 refers to a php session driver that ships with CI.  I see something similar on my install.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Sharing a solution that helped me, try set your config variable like:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Comment: Ion Auth should verify this path before trying to do things and crash all the application.

Comment: In the default setting, this variable is set to NULL, Just change it to sys_get_temp_dir();

Comment: I did not think that would work, but it did. How did you know?

Comment: It does give error with this info. This error comes when we use directory bases session approach. use db based session approach error will go.

Answer (score 16):

This error comes when we use directory bases session approach in CodeIgniter. If we use database based session approach error will go. Use code below -

change your application->config->config.php and set

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

& Run SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Answer (score 12):

In config.php `sess_save_path` should be `sys_get_temp_dir();` then it will resolve the error of `mkdir(): Invalid path`

Answer (score 6):

The reason you encountered the error is because you didn't have a `$config['sess_save_path']`

Go to you `config.php` and set

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

Comment: thanx but there is already  $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL; set in config.php

Comment: okk try to set it on path like `$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'yourfoldername/cache/';`

Answer (score 6):

1.Open the config.php on application/config folder

2.Browse all the way down to the `$config['sess_save_path'] =  NULL;` line.

3.Change the `NULL` value to `BASEPATH.'sessions'`

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to PHP and codeIgniter version. 
For me, PHP 7.1.25 and CI 3.0.4 didn't work. You can check with session_id(). Session was refreshed.
With CI 3.1.2 it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your config.php 
   `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use absolute path for `$config['sess_save_path']` in config file.
2. Point it to your writable temporary directory.
3. Make sure the directory is under the directory allowed in apache or nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

If `$config['sess_save_path']` is `sys_get_temp_dir()` then session data will store in system folder.

And If you have database table as ci_sessions with below config.php:

`$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';`

The data will store in database. In this case you can `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar case I have a multihost in godaddy and first I corrected the .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c> 
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Then correct the file config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)