# Codeigniter Sessions Do Not Work On Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When open codeigniter project localhost they work properly and open in server then error of invalid path

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mkdir(): Invalid path
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 117
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/garden_worx/index.php Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Error 2

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Exception
>
> Message: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't
>   exist or cannot be created.
>
> Filename:
>   /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/garden_worx/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 119
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/garden_worx/index.php Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Error 3

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen(6d898f163e36616cef220426dad109225a66f74a): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 156
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: Did any of the answer below help you if so make sure you accept one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter cannot load libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431910/codeigniter-cannot-load-libraries)

Answer (score 20):

This will be really helpful to you, it was save my day too :)

in your config.php

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Similar Question
[session error in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042456/when-i-want-to-use-session-in-codeigniter-it-says-error-why?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you. There was some server restriction to my base folder. The way you've given is certainly the preferred way.

Answer (score 12):

In codeigniter 3 versions you can use files or database if files, make sure you have created folder where you would like your session path set and chmod 700

I use cache folder to store files sessions

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Auto load session in application > config > autoload

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

> **Note:** Make sure all **file names** and **class names** of controllers,
>   models, libraries have first letter upper case example filename `Welcome.php` and `class Welcome extends CI_Controller {}`.

Codeigniter doc's 2 and 3 http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Codeigniter 3 session http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Codeigniter 2 session: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

You also may need to have a encryption_key on config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'pXeQY2733rR560MrwJy40OL4WaSGmr5A';
```

http://randomkeygen.com/

Comment: i try it still they are not work plz give me another idea

Comment: where we set chmod 777

Comment: What is your version of codeigniter and update your question with your session configs.

Comment: I am not sure if your using live server if you are you can right click folder on ftp and then go to permissions.

Comment: It also could be your file name issue please read note: area.

Comment: i used intranet server like eg. 203.2.3.3  also use codeigniter version 3 they work properly in localhost server but problem in put in server then session file error  "Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created."

Comment: used intranet server like eg. 203.2.3.3 also use codeigniter version 3 they work properly in localhost server but problem in put in server then session file error "Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created."

Comment: @Carpetsmoker what would you use for chmod 0644 ?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 A directory usually needs executable permissions, otherwise you can't search it (i.e. use `ls`, `cd`) `664` is just read and write, but not execute (see link in earlier comment). You typically need to either set the user or group to whoever needs to write this (with `chown`). In this case, the user running PHP (often `www` or `www-data`, but it depends on the system), and then `755` is enough. In fact, for session data I would use the even stricter `700` since even *reading* this can be a security risk (I can steal your login token and login as you).

Comment: Thanks for explaining it now

Answer (score 2):

Simply change this in your, `application -> config -> config.php`

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

To

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH.'ci_sessions';
```

It will create a Directory in your Root.
Hopefully your problem will solve ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also put

```
output_buffering = On
```

in your php.ini file on the root

Answer (score 0):

Change 'NULL' to either '/tmp' or your servers temp folder path

The line should now read:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';
```

Answer (score -1):

adding 'session' in autoload.php file solved my problem

$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation','session');

Answer (score -2):

This work for me

`$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();`