# codeingniter3.0.6 is not working in Godaddy server only

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter 3.0.6 is working in local and HostGator, but not working in GoDaddy server.
My Url is `http://domain.com/PHP/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/admin/login` looks like.
Controller path: `application/controller/admin/login.php`

> Error: Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mkdir(): Invalid path
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 117

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The error is telling you something.  On GoDaddy, did you create the specified folder for your session files and give it the proper permissions?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/34281557/594235

Comment: Thank you, It is working fine....
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/sessions/';
in config.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practices is that save the session to database.
`$config['sess_save_path'] = 'database'`.

But make sure to create a table called `ci_sessions` on your application database.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.
It is working fine.... $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/sessions/'; in config.php file