# My database user exists, but I still get an (HY000/2002): No such file or directoryc please solve

Tags: php, codeigniter

My database user exists, but I still get an (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
i m using this config/database.php but showing error
note.. i m trying on cpanel linux platform based

Comment: Can you show the code you've written and indicate exactly where you're getting an error?

Comment: Check make sure you have followed the correct filename and class naming way for the files controller, model, libraries etc. Where **Only** the first letter is upper case the rest lower case. As explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: open link showing error please help http://www.catermanage.co.uk/

Comment: you can check with this link for your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042456/session-error-in-codeigniter